# use javascript to remove the last html element

Tags: javascript, html

Lets say I have a webpage like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
//code that deletes the last element
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>nothing important in the body</h1>
</body>
</html>

<!-- and then there is another script element that I want to remove with javascript:  -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="example.com"></script>
```

How could I remove the last script element using javascript?

Comment: just curious… how does that script end up after the end of the document?

Comment: I decided to use a free webhost one day, and it loads in a popup ad code. I found nothing in the terms of service that says I cant try to remove the code

Comment: I suspected it might be the case. As I've written in my updated answer, you won't be able to prevent the script's execution. You'll have to let it happen, then remove the damage (not the script, but the crap it will add to your page).

Comment: I'll try to find the function that closes the popup

Comment: maybe you should reformulate your question to state your purpose (which is to prevent or revert the script's execution rather than just removing it). Might be a way…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first you should see what browsers actually do with that. An HTML document cannot have elements outside the document root, or even outside `<head>` and `<body>`. Let's say `src` contains your HTML source:

```
new DOMParser().parseFromString(src, "text/html")
```

returns a Document where the script has been moved to the bottom of `<body>`.

Now you know where it is in the parsed DOM, you can figure out how to remove it, right?

```
document.body.removeChild(document.body.lastElementChild)
```

However, since it is at the bottom of the document, you cannot run that code at load time (unless you add another script even below that one), because the script you want to remove won't be in the DOM until the parser moves beyond the HTML end tag. So you need to wait for the DOM load event.

And there is just no way to remove it before the script is evaluated, if that was your purpose.

**However**, if you want to *prevent the script from being parsed*, you can add an unclosed comment `<!--` at the very end of your page (after `</html>`). That will comment out the script, unless it comes with a defensive `-->`.

Comment: hmmmm, is there another way to stop the script from being executed?

Comment: @Mashpoe hmmm maybe if you craft your document so that the injected `<script>` tag is not parsed as a tag…

Comment: it works! there is currently no defense because the script is loaded in from another website and there is no --> before the script tag